# Vuetify:how to change border color when I focus on v-text-field?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to put label inside the v-text-field. Is there a way to add color on border-top, border-right, border-left when I click on the v-text-field to make the border appear just like the border-bottom?

https://codepen.io/magooo/pen/KKaRVVa

```html
<v-app id="app">
    <v-content class="mt-3 mx-5">
       <v-text-field
         dense
         filled
         label="Text field 1"
         ></v-text-field>
    </v-content>
</v-app>
```

Comment: You can use an outlined text field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `v-text-field` gets focus, it applies the `.v-input--is-focused` CSS class, which could be used to style the `.v-input-slot`'s border upon focus:

```css
.v-input--is-focused .v-input__slot {
  border: 2px solid #005fcc !important;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38) !important;
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/vYgjLjY?editors=1100)